# 500 Internal server error during item creation using Sitecore.services.client

Tags: sitecore-services-client

I tried to create an item using **Item Service** in **Sitecore.Services.Client**.
But when I try to create an item am facing

> 500 Internal server not found

error during item creation.

Below I attached the code sample that I used.

```
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("POST", "http://sitecore91.sc/sitecore/api/ssc/item/sitecore/content/Home ");
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (this.readyState == 4) {
                        alert('Status: ' + this.status + '\nHeaders: ' + JSON.stringify(this.getAllResponseHeaders()) + '\nBody: ' + this.responseText);
                    }
                };
                xhr.send("{\"ItemName\": \"Home\",\"TemplateID\": \"76036f5e-cbce-46d1-af0a-4143f9b557aa\"}");
```

Comment: Can you hit the endpoint with postman? Are there any entries in the log files that might be related? My off the cuff guess is that the Item API is not enabled.

Comment: i checked with postman ,nothing get's returned. where i need to enable item API?

Comment: Could not find any recent docs, have a look at https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/modules/sitecore%20item%20web%20api/sitecore_item_web_api_developer_guide_sc65-66-usletter.pdf see Security on page 12. Not sure if this is still current sorry

Comment: Also if you are using Sitecore 9.1 look into JSS.

Comment: Not working. I Changed and checked. but this is used when we use item web api but i'm using sitecore.services.client .

Comment: Can you find anything in the logs that might help?

Comment: Hi, GTHvidson it's permission related issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to provide access rights to sitecore\ServicesAPI user.
I was fixed that error by setting admin rights to

> sitecore\ServicesAPI

user in usermanger.

Comment: This solution should be applied with extreme care. Anonymous requests run under the security context of this account by default so you are effectively giving admin access to anonymous users.

Comment: yes. That's true

Answer (score 0):

According to the [ItemService documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-management/en/the-restful-api-for-the-itemservice.html), the item path needs to be URL encoded, and your code does not do this.

Where your code does the following:

`xhr.open("POST", "http://sitecore91.sc/sitecore/api/ssc/item/sitecore/content/Home ");`

The proper way should be this:

`xhr.open("POST", "http://sitecore91.sc/sitecore/api/ssc/item/sitecore%2Fcontent%2Fhome");`

Comment: I tried this also. but it's not working for me. still am facing 500 internal server error.

Comment: <setting name="Sitecore.Services.SecurityPolicy" value="Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Web.Http.Security.ServicesOnPolicy, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure" />
i have changed the security policy & anonymous user to true also.

Comment: note: Get Request for item Getting is working